# Division by 0 Error when checking whether something is equal to zero

Tags: evaluation, algebraic-manipulation

I was running a program and suddenly got `Divide::infy` messages coming from the following (rather ugly) expression.

```
1 - 2 I E^(2 I \[Pi] (ArcTan[(1/Sqrt[2] - 2 Cos[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]] - Sqrt[2] Cos[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]])/Sqrt[ 2] + (-(1/Sqrt[2]) - 2 Sin[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]] - Sqrt[2] Sin[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]])/Sqrt[ 2], -((1/Sqrt[2] - 2 Cos[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]] - Sqrt[2] Cos[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]])/Sqrt[2]) + (-(1/Sqrt[2]) - 2 Sin[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]] - Sqrt[2] Sin[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]])/Sqrt[ 2]]/(2 \[Pi]) - (I Log[(-((1/Sqrt[2] - 2 Cos[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]] - Sqrt[2] Cos[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]])/ Sqrt[2]) + (-(1/Sqrt[2]) -2 Sin[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]] -Sqrt[2] Sin[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]])/ Sqrt[2])^2 + ((1/Sqrt[2] - 2 Cos[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]] -Sqrt[2] Cos[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]])/ Sqrt[2] + (-(1/Sqrt[2]) - 2 Sin[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]] -Sqrt[2] Sin[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]])/ Sqrt[2])^2])/(4 \[Pi]))) + E^(4 I \[Pi] (ArcTan[(1/Sqrt[2] - 2 Cos[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]] -Sqrt[2] Cos[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]])/ Sqrt[2] + (-(1/Sqrt[2]) - 2 Sin[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]] -Sqrt[2] Sin[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]])/ Sqrt[2], -((1/Sqrt[2] - 2 Cos[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]] -Sqrt[2] Cos[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]])/ Sqrt[2]) + (-(1/Sqrt[2]) - 2 Sin[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]] -Sqrt[2] Sin[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]])/ Sqrt[2]]/(2 \[Pi]) - (I Log[(-((1/Sqrt[2] - 2 Cos[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]] - Sqrt[2] Cos[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]])/Sqrt[2]) + (-(1/Sqrt[2]) - 2 Sin[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]] - Sqrt[2] Sin[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]])/Sqrt[ 2])^2 + ((1/Sqrt[2] - 2 Cos[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]] - Sqrt[2] Cos[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]])/Sqrt[ 2] + (-(1/Sqrt[2]) - 2 Sin[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]] - Sqrt[2] Sin[2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]])/Sqrt[2])^2])/(4 \[Pi])))
== 0
```

The interesting thing is that when removing the `== 0` everything evaluates fine. Applying `Simplify` to the LHS before checking equality with `0` also works fine. Can other people replicate this strange behaviour?
I'm using Mathematica 12.3.1.0. on macOS Catalina 10.15.17

Comment: It happens to me in V13.0.1 (Mac). `Equal` is checking something, I suspect.  It probably rejects the step that divides by `0`.  Usually one gets `Power::infy` instead of `Divide::infy` so it's almost certainly some internal transformation.

Comment: I just verified the same in `V12.0.0`

Comment: Probably a small bug that those messages leak (that is, get printed rather than suppressed). Might or might not be a bug that the divisions occur in the inner workings of `Equal`.

Comment: Same in 12.3.1.0  and 12.1.0.0 (Windows 10)